# Stop jQuery Mouseleave Event When Entering Another Specific Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know how I can stop my mouseleave event from occuring when I slide my mouse over to a different element (link).  How can I setup a condition that says to only do the mouseleave animation if I have not entered a specific element?

```
$(activity_link).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".delete_place").animate({ 
                                               "left" : "-28px"
                                              }, 300);     
}).mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).siblings(".delete_place").animate({
                                                "left" : 0
                                               }, 300);
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include your html and the specifics of this element.  Often the approach is to make this element a child of the main element and position it absolutely.  But this is very dependent on the specifics.

Comment: You probably should add a bit more to your question, as there may be a better way to solve your overall problem than with a `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave`.

Answer (score 4):

Use of event relatedTarget:

```
$(activity_link).mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".delete_place").animate({
        "left": "-28px"
    }, 300);
}).mouseleave(function (e) {
    if (e.relatedTarget != myElem) { //where myElem is a HTML element
        $(this).siblings(".delete_place").animate({
            "left": 0
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

Comment: relatedTarget is really awesome! Thanks :)

Comment: In this case, `mouseleave` event will not be executed again when you leave `myElem`. I think it should be executed when your mouse leaves either `activity_link` or `myElem`. Do you have any solution? Since I've exactly [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45126197/how-can-i-select-everything-except-specific-element).

Answer (score -1):

you could stop the event and prevent it from bubbling/firing:

```
...
}).mouseleave(function(event) {
    if(mycondition) {
        $(this).siblings(".delete_place").animate({"left" : 0}, 300);
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I think the question is what to write as "mycondition"?