# How can I select everything except specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$.fn.right = function() {
   return $(document).width() - (this.offset().left + this.outerWidth());
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    this.iid = setTimeout(function() {
      var tag_name = self.text(),
          top      = self.position().top + self.outerHeight(true),
          right = self.right();
      $('body').append("<div class='tag_info'>Some explanations about "+tag_name+"</div>");
      
      $(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", right: right + "px"}).fadeIn(200);  
      
    }, 525);
  }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    if(this.iid){
      clearTimeout(this.iid)
      $('.tag_info').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
    body{
      padding: 20px;
      direction: rtl;
    }

    a {
        color: #3e6d8e !important;
        background-color: #E1ECF4;
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }
    .tag_info{
      position: absolute;
      width: 130px;
      height: 100px;
      display:none;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a>long-length-tag</a>
    <a>tag</a>
```

It works as well and that pop-up will be removed when your mouse leaves the tag. Now I want to keep that pop-up when the mouse leaves the tag and goes on that pop-up. Otherwise it should be removed. How can I do that?

Comment: OT: Take a look at getBoundingClientRect (instead of your right function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a condition to check if the mouse is hovering over the pop-up before removing it:

`if ($('.tag_info:hover').length == 0) {....}`

And you need to add an event on the pop-up itself to remove it on `mouseleave`

**See code snippet:**

```js
$.fn.right = function() {
  return $(document).width() - (this.offset().left + this.outerWidth());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    this.iid = setTimeout(function() {
      var tag_name = self.text(),
        top = self.position().top + self.outerHeight(true),
        right = self.right();
        
      var pop_up = $('<div />', {
        "class": 'tag_info',
        text: "Some explanations about " + tag_name,
        mouseleave: function(e){
             $(this).remove();
        }})  
      
      $('body').append(pop_up);

      $(".tag_info").css({
        top: top + "px",
        right: right + "px"
      }).fadeIn(200);

    }, 525);
  }).bind('mouseleave', function() {
    if (this.iid) {
      clearTimeout(this.iid)
      if ($('.tag_info:hover').length == 0) {
        $('.tag_info').remove();
      }
    }
  });


});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  direction: rtl;
}

a {
  color: #3e6d8e !important;
  background-color: #E1ECF4;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.tag_info {
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>long-length-tag</a>
<a>tag</a>
```

Comment: Cannot I use `:not()` ?

Comment: @stack In what context you want to use `:not()`?

Comment: I meant using `.on()` instead of `.bind()` like this: `}).on('mouseleave', 'a:not(.tag_info)' function() {` ..! Thank you anyway. upvote

Comment: @stack you can use it if that is what you need ... and `a:not(.tag_info)` will select every `<a>` tag except the tags that doesn't have the class `tag_info.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to keep that pop-up when the mouse leaves the tag and goes on that pop-up.

You could use [`MouseEvent.relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget) to check which element the mouse left to.

If you add an event listener on `mouseleave`, an event object the is passed into the event callback when the mouse leaves the element. In that event object is the property `relateTarget` which is a pointer to the element the mouse left on to. So if the mouse leaves the element on to the `tag_info` element, you can make the info not be hidden.

You can also wrap the event in a jquery selector to create a jquery object if you prefer like so:

```
$(e.relateTarget) // do something with the jquery object
```

**Try hovering over the tag and then pointing your mouse on top of the `tag_info`**

Hopefully that helps!

```js
$.fn.right = function() {
  return $(document).width() - (this.offset().left + this.outerWidth());
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var iid = this.iid = setTimeout(function() {
      var tag_name = self.text(),
        top = self.position().top + self.outerHeight(true),
        right = self.right();
      $('body').append("<div class='tag_info'>Some explanations about " + tag_name + "</div>");

      var tagInfo = $(".tag_info");
      
      tagInfo.css({
        top: top + "px",
        right: right + "px"
      }).fadeIn(200);
      
      tagInfo.bind('mouseleave', function (e) {
        console.log('mouse left tag info');
        if (iid) {
          clearTimeout(iid)
          tagInfo.remove();
        }
      });

    }, 525);
  }).bind('mouseleave', function(e) {
    //this is the event callback and the event object is `e`
    if (e.relatedTarget && e.relatedTarget.classList.contains('tag_info')) {
      console.log('mouse left onto the tag_info');
    } else {
      console.log('mouse left onto something else');
      if (this.iid) {
        clearTimeout(this.iid)
        $('.tag_info').remove();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  direction: rtl;
}

a {
  color: #3e6d8e !important;
  background-color: #E1ECF4;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.tag_info {
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>long-length-tag</a>
<a>tag</a>
```

Comment: Cannot I use `:not()` ?

Comment: @stack I guess you could but I'd say it'd be unnecessary. The selector `$(*:not(.tag_info))` will have a length as long as any element that isn't a `tag_info` and that's a very very big list. You would not want to use that selector because it's inefficient.

Comment: @stack I also updated my answer to work properly instead of just giving you the idea